# saving json data into sqlite database in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, sqlite, relational-database

My question is how to insert a fetched JSON array data into sqlite database.
I have fetched JSON data which is an array of dictionaries.

My code to save JSON result looks like this:

```
-(BOOL) saveApiResults: (NSString *)tableName : (NSArray *)data
{
    BOOL saveSuccess = NO;

    @try {
        const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_open(dbPath,&database)==SQLITE_OK) {

            sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);

            //pass an array containing json dictionary to below line
            NSDictionary *rowData=[data objectAtIndex:0];
            NSArray *keyArray = [rowData allKeys];
            NSLog(@"key array %@",keyArray);
            NSString *insertSQL=@"INSERT INTO ";
            insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@"moodsdata"];
            insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@" VALUES("];
            for(int j=0;j<[keyArray count];j++)
            {
                insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@"?"];
                if(j<[keyArray count]-1)
                    insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@","];
            }
            insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@");"];


            NSLog(@"query : %@ ",insertSQL);

            const char *sqlstatement = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlstatement , -1, &compiledstatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

                for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [data count]; i++) {
                    NSDictionary *rowData=[data objectAtIndex:0];
                    for(int j=0;j<[keyArray count];j++) {
                        NSString *val = @"";
                        NSString *value=(NSString *)[rowData objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:j]];
                        if((value != nil) && (![value isEqual:[NSNull null]]))
                            val=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];
                        NSLog(@"values  %@",val);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledstatement,j+1,[val UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    }

                    if(sqlite3_step(compiledstatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                        NSLog(@"ERROR");
                    }

                    sqlite3_clear_bindings(compiledstatement);
                    sqlite3_reset(compiledstatement);


                }

                sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
                saveSuccess = YES;
                NSLog(@"RESULTS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!");


            } else {
                NSLog(@"StatemenT FAILED (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Statement FAILED (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"NSException : %@",exception.description);
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    return saveSuccess;
}
```

My question is when I try to pass the JSON array to this method it only saves the value for first array object . i.e. only first dictionary values get saved. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please update your question with code relevant to your question. What have you tried so far? The code in your question has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Unrelated but why are you building the `CREATE` statement that way? Why isn't it a single string literal? At least use `NSMutableString` to build it up piece by piece.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You primary issue is that you mistakenly access `data[0]` instead of `data[i]` in your loop that does the actual inserting.

But there are lots of other little issues with this code. Here's your code all cleaned up:

```
-(BOOL) saveApiResults:(NSString *)tableName data:(NSArray *)data
{
    BOOL saveSuccess = NO;

    const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath,&database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);

        //pass an array containing json dictionary to below line
        NSDictionary *rowData = data[0];
        NSArray *keyArray = [rowData allKeys];
        NSLog(@"key array %@",keyArray);

        NSMutableString *insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO moods data VALUES(";
        for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [keyArray count]; j++)
        {
            if (j) {
                [insertSQL appendString:@","];
            }
            [insertSQL appendString:@"?"];
        }
        [insertSQL appendString:@");"];
        NSLog(@"query : %@ ",insertSQL);

        const char *sqlstatement = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlstatement, -1, &compiledstatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            for (NSDictionary *rowData in data) {
                for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [keyArray count]; j++) {
                    NSString *val = @"";
                    NSString *value = rowData[keyArray[j];
                    if (value && ![value isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                        val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];
                    }
                    NSLog(@"values %@",val);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(compiled statement, j + 1, [val UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                }

                if (sqlite3_step(compiledstatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR");
                }

                sqlite3_reset(compiledstatement);
            }

            sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);
            saveSuccess = YES;
            NSLog(@"RESULTS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"StatemenTtFAILED (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_close(database);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Statement FAILED (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    return saveSuccess;
}
```

1. There is no need for `try/catch`. Just do proper error checking.
2. Use `NSMutableString` to build up a string piece by piece.
3. Only finalize a statement if you successfully prepare it.
4. Be sure to close a database if you open it.
5. Use modern syntax for accessing values from dictionaries and arrays. It's easier to read and type.
6. Use modern loops when possible.
7. Use whitespace. It makes the code easier to read.
8. Give all of your method parameters a name.

But your SQLite code was actually better than most posts here. You actually use `sqlite_bind_xxx` to bind values to your query. Too few people do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you're grabbing the values, you are grabbing the row data with:

```
NSDictionary *rowData=[data objectAtIndex:0];
```

I suspect you mean:

```
NSDictionary *rowData=[data objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: now i want to add one more column to the table. In my project i have a table view in which i display all the fetched data from the sqlite database. But now i want to save the value of the tableView cell. For example if i select first cell, then it should save it in databases new column and say 'moods 1 selected and saved', if i select third cell it should save it in databases new column and say 'moods 3 selected and saved', and so on... Can anyone help me out with this problem @Rob

Comment: I'm not quite following what you're asking. I'd suggest you post new question on Stack Overflow, showing us what you tried, what happened when you tried that, and describe what you wanted to happen. But there's not enough in your comment above for me to diagnose what's going on.